# Automatically selecting default in Unix terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, flags

I'm aware that a command such as `something -y` will force a yes answer on any response back from the terminal, but I'm having problems with getting Ansible to automate the process of configuration.  The module in question has defaults (a [no]) and the provisioning process hangs as I can't configure it to automatically select default answers.

Is there a way to run a command have the terminal automatically select defaults, as you can do with the `-y` flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to interact via a script with a program that doesn't allow you to select the correct options via command-line switches or an answers file for non-interactive operation, but only supports user interaction, you may want to take a look at [`expect`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

If you only need to answer a single question, then `yes` or `yes <answer>` is your friend.

Comment: Congrats on the 10k btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with a little creative crafting of the `yes` command.

`yes | script.sh`  or `yes | command` or if you wanted a "n", try `yes n | command`

Comment: Thanks!  I did this solution with a little crafting with Ansible. Since the default was no, I piped it in with the Ansible `shell` command.  I think `expect` is a better solution though.

Comment: `shell: '"no" | pecl install mongo'` was what finally got it.